# Password Authentication failed when using shp2psgsql

Tags: postgis, shp2pgsql

I want to load shp data in my postgis enabled database.
I am typing the command:

```
shp2pgsql -s 4326 -G -I "shapefile_name" public.table_name | 
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -d gis -U postgres
```

and I am prompted to enter my password. After entering the right password I get the following message:

```
psql: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

Is there a configuration that has to be made in the pg_hba.conf file?

Comment: Try setting PGPASSWORD=yourpassword after the Pipe and before the psql staement.

Comment: I deleted this part: -h localhost -p 5432 and it worked